# addEventListener is not working if put it in head section rather then body

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't know why this isn't working. In my HTML, if I put my script in the head section, I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

If I put my script in the bottom part of the body, it's working fine.

HTML :

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-img="img1" id="img1"> Shahin </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-img="img2" id="img2"> Lina   </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-img="img3" id="img3"> Adrita </a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="./img/1.jpg" class="hidden">
    <img src="./img/2.png" class="hidden">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" class="hidden">
</body>
```

JavaScript :

```
var shahin = document.getElementById('img1');
var lina = document.getElementById('img2');
var adrita = document.getElementById("img3");

shahin.addEventListener('click',picShow);
lina.addEventListener('click',picShow);
adrita.addEventListener('click',picShow);

function picShow() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and where is the proper place to put the script tag? Also, what change should I make to run my script from head section? I will be glad for your answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: The DOM has to load for you to be able to grab the elements and attach listeners. If your code is in the head, the DOM hasn't loaded before the script is run. Either wrap your code in a `onload` or ready wrapper, or move your code under the HTML

Comment: you need to put it in a `$(document).ready()` if it's in the head because your body hasn't been rendered yet when you add the handler

Comment: @jdubjdub, that would only work with jQuery.

Comment: whatever ready state thing you want to use is fine - just something that runs after the DOM is loaded

Answer (score 3):

Your script is loading and being executed prior to the rest of the body HTML, so naturally, `document.getElementById` is going to return null.

You should be running your event listener subscription code on or after the `document.ready` event.

Wrap the code you posted into a JS function, then set that function as the callback to be executed on document.ready:

`document.addEventListener('load', initFn);`

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` would work. Not so sure about `onload`.

Comment: Is the w3schools site no longer accurate? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: i tried with this code and its not showing anything on console... but no error as well 

`document.addEventListener('onload',function abc() {

    var shahin = document.getElementById('img1');
    var lina = document.getElementById('img2');
    var adrita = document.getElementById("img3");

    
    shahin.addEventListener('click',picShow);
    lina.addEventListener('click',picShow);
    adrita.addEventListener('click',picShow);

    function picShow() {

        console.log(this);

    }


});
`

Comment: I edited my answer -- try 'load' instead of 'onload' as the name of the event

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="script.js"> </script>
```

Add key word **defer**, script runs when all DOM elements will loaded

Answer (score 2):

If you put your `<script>` in the `<head>` javascript loading from top to bottom.
 So when loading it returns undefined eventlistener. 
So try use the script just before the end of your `</body>` tag and it will works.
Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Comment: can anybody please tell me what change should i do to work the script from head ? i tried to use
    document.addEventListener('onload',function abc() { and wrap the whole code inside it... still its not working...

Comment: use defer attribute

Answer (score 1):

Further to Josh E's answer:

> You should be running your event listener subscription code on or after the document.ready event

If you want to execute your code as soon as the element is available, you can use `requestAnimationFrame` to scan the DOM during page load instead of waiting for the entire page to load:

```
function doSomethingWithElement(myElement) {
    myElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Do stuff here
    });
}

function searchForElement() {
    const el = document.getElementById('img1');
    if (el) {
       return doSomethingWithEl(el); 
    }
    window.searchID = window.requestAnimationFrame(searchForElement);
}

// Store the request ID so it can be cancelled later
// Otherwise it'll run forever!
window.searchID = window.requestAnimationFrame(searchForElement);
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(window.searchID);
});
```

This might be overkill but it's super useful when you want to manipulate or add listeners to DOM elements as soon as is possible.